# By default, BabelJS doesn't transpile anonymous function of ES6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, anonymous-function, babeljs

I'm using Babel 6.1.2

```
$ babel --version
6.1.2 (babel-core 6.1.2)
```

When I compile ES6 code with anoymous function, I found the code is not transpiled to ECMAScript 5 Syntax at all.

```
$ echo "()=>1" | babel 
() => 1;
```

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: It seems this question is asked every day at least once. Please use the search!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official 6.0 release blogpost (https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0/):

*Since Babel is focusing on being a platform for JavaScript tooling and not an ES2015 transpiler, we’ve decided to make all of the plugins opt-in. This means when you install Babel it will no longer transpile your ES2015 code by default.*

You will need plugins or presets to actually transpile your code.

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets

Answer (score 1):

Found a way:

Install  the plugin

```
$ npm install babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions
```

Add the following to `.babelrc`

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-arrow-functions"]
}
```

Then it works

```
$ echo "() => 1" | babel --plugins transform-es2015-arrow-functions 
(function () {
  return 1;
});
```